# How to retrieve data from the post request?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I'm using `Spring MVC 4.1.3`.
I need to allow user to save new data into a database. I've created the form.

```
<form id="add" action="/dosave" method="POST">
<!-- Some input/texts, e.g.: -->
<input type="text" id="name" /> <br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dosave", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSave(@RequestParam String name, Model m){
    eDAO.addE(name);
    return "view";
}
```

The issue is when I click to the submit button the url doesn't contain the request parameters with the data that user provided. Am I going to have to write `JavaScript` code to manually pass that data into the `URL` string? I tried to change the method from `POST` to `GET` but it didn't work. What was I doing wrong, couldn't you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define name for input box :

```
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature should be

```
public String doSave(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model m)
```

Also, make sure the class is marked with @Controller and that it is loaded by the context